# Duplicate Object after .click() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I need a help,

i have .click() event for adding some value into my table.

```
$("#ButtonSave").click(function()

    {
        var someObject: myCurrentObject = new myCurrentObject();

        someObject.A = String($("someInputTextId").val());
        someObject.B = String($("someInputTextId").val());
    }
});
```

for first click, after i put console.log(someObject); show correct result. and in second click, someOject value already flushed, but become duplicate.

any solution?

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: Sounds like you have misspelled your variable and thus getting global scope? Check your variable names and and a linter (TSLint for typescript) to catch errors like that in the future. If you want to get easier click and tap handling you can try a library for that to get rid of those eventHandlers. I have made one called GoodTap and you can get it on npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/goodtap

Comment: i already got a solution from my co-worker yesterday, so he told me like I need to put my variable to out of the function. so thats mean i need to make it global.

Comment: by the way, thats for the response @JGoodgive.

Comment: Read up on how function scopes work in javascript. It is really key to the language. Also try and avoid making things global. It is enough that you move the variable out in the next outer function scope.